# How to create a directory using the Databricks API

Tags: curl, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to make a directory using the Databricks API, but I'm struggling to find the right placeholders in the cURL request.

I tried to create directory using mkdirs, no luck!

```
curl -X POST https://${DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/dbfs/mkdirs -H "Authorization: Bearer ${DATABRICKS_TOKEN}" -d {path:dbfs/mnt}
```

But the below GET requests works fine with the provided host and token in my environment:

```
curl -X GET "https://${DATABRICKS_HOST}/api/2.0/clusters/get" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${DATABRICKS_TOKEN}" -d '{ "cluster_id": "<0101-654123-is5wcaq7>" }'
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data in a JSON string format as you did for the get
request on the cluster.

[image]

```
 curl -X POST "https://<host>/api/2.0/dbfs/mkdirs" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -d '{"path": "/curl_dir/"}'
```

[image]